# Is this a strict Lower bound on the amount of numbers less than x but coprime to y?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, probabilistic-method, combinatorial-number-theory

Let $\Lambda(x,y)$ be the relative totient function that counts the amount of numbers less than $x$, which are coprime to $y$.

After interpreting Euler's totient function, $\phi(y)$, as a result of combinatorics and modulo arithmetic, I've tried to interpret $\Lambda(x,y)$ as a result of combinatorics and modulo arithmetic too and reached the following form, I would like to complete:

$$\Lambda(x,y) \geq \frac{x}{y}\phi(y) + V$$

Obviously, if $x$ is a multiple of $y$, then $V=0$, because that's a well established fact. But considering $x$ as a non-multiple of $y$; I note that $\phi(y)$ has product form derivable from combinatorics and modulo arithmetic, and that any term in that product involving a prime divisor of both $x$ and $y$ cannot produce error. But any term in that product involving a prime divisor of just $y$ can produce error. So the question is how much, and consequently, what is $V$?

In the worst case, for any prime $p$ divisor of only $y$ and not $x$, the corresponding term in Euler's product would be errorless up to a value, let's label $c_{p}$, where $c_{p}$ is the largest multiple of $p$ less than $x$. So the largest error that the term in Euler's product can make in this relative totient function formulation, is to predict too many totatives of $p$ between $c_{p}$ and $x$, so there's an argument that the upper bound to that amount would be $p - 1$, the largest possible remainder when dividing by $p$.

After considering all of the primes divisors of $y$ which are not divisors of $x$; the prime $q$ which is the largest of those primes, can feasibly cause the largest error, because $c_{q}$ could be the maximum distance away from $x$. Assuming the worst case, that $c_{q} = x - q + 1$, then we can argue that the upper bound of the amount of extra totatives predicted by Euler's product is $q-1$, and any error due to other primes $p$, which are only divisors of $y$, is subsumed by the error caused by $q$, because $c_{p} > c_{q}$ and all $p-1$ at most incorrect totatives, are already included in this formulation as incorrect totatives of $q$.

So $V\geq -(q-1)$ to ammend the error derived above, and $$\Lambda(x,y) \geq \frac{x}{y}\phi(y) - q$$ where $q$ is the largest prime divisor of $y$ but not $x$.

How sound is this analysis?

---

**EDIT**
This is a more formal version.

> **Lemma** $$\Lambda(x,y) > \frac{x}{y} \phi(y) - z$$ where $z$ is the largest prime that divides $y$, but doesn't divide $x$, $y$ is larger than $x$, and $x$ is larger than all prime divisors of $y$

Let $D_y := \{d : (d,y) \neq 1 \}$ and $P_y := \{p : p \in D_y \cap \mathbb{P}  \}$ and $Q_{(x,y)} := \{q : q \in P_y$ and $q \mid x \}$ and $R_{(x,y)} := \{r : r \in P_y$ and $r \nmid x \}$.

I'm going to use some made up notation in the next part because I have no idea how to write this succinctly otherwise. Unfortunately, the left subscripts may shift a little, apologies in advance.

> Let ${}_a\mid \Sigma p \mathbb{Z} \mid _b$ be the result of counting all elements in $p\mathbb{Z}$ bounded in the set $[a,b]$, for each $p \in P_y$. (So multiples may be counted more than one time).

> Let ${}_a\mid D_y \mid _b$ be the amount of elements in the set $D_y$ that are bounded to the set $[a,b]$

With this style of notation, hopefully the rest expresses as I mean.

By exhaustion with duplication ${}_0\mid D_y \mid _y \leq {}_0\mid \Sigma p \mathbb{Z} \mid _y$.

By classifying primes then  ${}_0\mid \Sigma p \mathbb{Z} \mid _y =  {}_0\mid \Sigma q \mathbb{Z} \mid _y  + {}_0\mid \Sigma r \mathbb{Z} \mid _y$ for $q \in Q_{(x,y)}$ and $r \in R_{(x,y)}$

By partitioning ${}_0\mid \Sigma p \mathbb{Z} \mid _y \leq {}_0\mid \Sigma q \mathbb{Z} \mid _x  + {}_x\mid \Sigma q \mathbb{Z} \mid _y + {}_0\mid \Sigma r \mathbb{Z} \mid _x + {}_x\mid \Sigma r \mathbb{Z} \mid _y $ for $q \in Q_{(x,y)}$ and $r \in R_{(x,y)}$.

Then ${}_0\mid D_y \mid _y \leq {}_0\mid \Sigma q \mathbb{Z} \mid _x  + {}_x\mid \Sigma q \mathbb{Z} \mid _y + {}_0\mid \Sigma r \mathbb{Z} \mid _x + {}_x\mid \Sigma r \mathbb{Z} \mid _y $

It follows by partitioning that ${}_0\mid D_y \mid _x \leq {}_0\mid \Sigma q \mathbb{Z} \mid _x + {}_0\mid \Sigma r \mathbb{Z} \mid _x$.

By definition  $\Lambda(x,y) = x - {}_0\mid D_y \mid _x$

So $\Lambda(x,y) \geq x - {}_0\mid \Sigma q \mathbb{Z} \mid _x - {}_0\mid \Sigma r \mathbb{Z} \mid _x$.

> Let ${}_a\mid \{ \Sigma p \mathbb{Z} \} \mid _b$ be the result of counting all elements in $p\mathbb{Z}$ bounded in the set $[a,b]$, for each $p \in P_y$, but not counting duplicates.

Then it still must be true that $\Lambda(x,y) \geq x - {}_0\mid \{ \Sigma q \mathbb{Z} \}\mid _x - {}_0\mid \{ \Sigma r \mathbb{Z} \} \mid _x$ because some non totatives of $y$ may be multiples of elements from both $Q_{(x,y)} $ and $R_{(x,y)} $

Note as well that $\phi(y) = y - {}_0\mid D_y \mid _y$.

Then $\phi(y) = y - {}_0\mid \{ \Sigma q \mathbb{Z} \} \mid _y  - \mid Z_{(x,y)} \mid $ where $Z_{(x,y)}$ is a subset of $\{ \Sigma r \mathbb{Z} \} $ that shares no elements with $\{ \Sigma q \mathbb{Z} \} $.

So $ \frac{x}{y}\phi(y) = x - \frac{x}{y}{}_0\mid \{\Sigma q \mathbb{Z} \} \mid _y  - \frac{x}{y} \mid Z_{(x,y)} \mid$

And $ \frac{x}{y}\phi(y) = x - {}_0\mid \{\Sigma q \mathbb{Z} \} \mid _x  - \frac{x}{y} \mid Z_{(x,y)} \mid$

The proof attempt stops here, so I think I answered my own question.

Comment: Reading the more formal version, I noticed that it is not correct that $\phi(y)=y - {}_0\mid D_y \mid _y$. For $(x,y)=(7,12)$, for example,  $\phi(y)=4\not=12-9=y - {}_0\mid D_y \mid _y$.

Comment: You might be right, but can I ask how you got $9$? I counted 8, with the elements being $2,3,4,6,8,9,10,12$?

Comment: By the definition, $0$ is included. You might want to replace $[a,b]$ with $(a,b]$ in the definition.

Comment: Good eye, thank you.

Comment: FYI : Such a prime number $q$ does not exist iff every prime divisor of $y$ divides $x$. One can show that if every prime divisor of $y$ divides $x$, then $\Lambda(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}\phi(y)$.

Comment: Yeah I did realize that. If you look at the last two math lines of my edit, I used that to jump from the first one to the second. The difficult I have now is simplifying $\frac{x}{y} \mid Z_{(x,y)} \mid$. I wanted to use the pigeonhole principle to show that this value is at most ${}_0\mid \cup r \mathbb{Z} - \cup q \mathbb{Z} \mid_{x} + z$, by showing all error maps to the partition $[x-z, x]$, but formalising that, if its even true, isn't easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the bound you obtained
$$
\Lambda(x,y) \geq \frac{x}{y}\phi(y) - q
$$
where $q$ is the largest prime divisor of $y$ but not $x$, this lower bound becomes useless if $q=y$ is prime larger than $x$. To see this, the lower bound becomes negative.
$$
\frac xy\phi(y) -q \leq x-q <0. 
$$

To amend this situation, we must have a good error term between $\Lambda(x,y)$ and $\frac xy \phi(y)$. A standard method is applying Mobius function $\mu(n)$.

$$
\begin{align}
\Lambda(x,y)&=\sum_{\substack{{n\leq x}\\{(n,y)=1}}} 1=\sum_{n\leq x} \sum_{\substack{{d|n}\\{d|y}}}\mu(d)\\
&=\sum_{d|y} \mu(d)\sum_{k\leq \frac xd} 1 \ \ (\text{by }n=dk)\\
&=\sum_{d|y} \mu(d)\left(\frac xd - \left\{ \frac xd \right\}\right)\\
&=\sum_{d|y} x \frac{\mu(d)}d- \sum_{d|y}\mu(d)\left\{ \frac xd \right\} \ \ (\{a\}\text{ is the fractional part of }a, \ \lfloor a \rfloor = a - \{a\}. )\\
&=\frac xy \phi(y)-\sum_{d|y}\mu(d)\left\{ \frac xd \right\}.\end{align}
$$
The error term here is
$$
E(x,y)=-\sum_{d|y}\mu(d)\left\{ \frac xd \right\}.
$$
This error term has an estimate
$$
|E(x,y)|\leq \sum_{d|y}|\mu(d)|=2^{\omega(y)}
$$
where $\omega(y)$ is the number of distinct prime divisors of $y$. It is also used sometimes that $2^{\omega(y)}\leq \tau(y)$ with the number-of-divisor function $\tau(y)$.

Hence, we have the lower bound of $\Lambda(x,y)$ given as
$$
\Lambda(x,y)\geq \frac xy \phi(y) - 2^{\omega(y)}
$$
or
$$
\Lambda(x,y)\geq \frac xy \phi(y)-\tau(y).
$$
An advantage of these bounds are that $\tau(y)$ is small compared to $y$. In fact,
$$
\tau(y)\leq y^{\frac{\log 2}{\log\log y} + O\left(\frac1{(\log\log y)^2}\right)}.
$$

Comment: Beautiful answer, thank you. I still need to wrap my head around mobius transforms, and incidence algebra, and so I appreciate seeing the mobius function in action. That's one of the reasons I resorted to counting argument. The other motivation behind the bound, is in the application of counting primes using the formula: $\pi(x) = \Lambda(x,p_{i}\#) + i -1 $. ($p_{i}\#$ stands for the product of primes upto $p_i$). For that case $y$ is usually much larger than $x$, yet $q$ is much lower.

Comment: An upper bound on $q$ is $\sqrt(x)$ because all composite numbers up to "the next largest prime, squared", (which is larger than $x$), are divisible by a prime upto $q$.

Comment: I did not have a good understanding of your $q$. But, I think you can use the error term formula $E(x,y)$ in my answer.

Comment: I didn't explain the context very well. Hopefully you can see how $ \Lambda(x,p_{i}\#) + i -1 $ is a prime sieve upto $p_{i+1}^2$, as any totatives to $p_{i}\#$ less than $p_{i+1}^2$, are either primes larger than $p_{i}$, or the number 1 (as all multiples have a factor of a prime upto $p_i$. But there are $i$ amount of primes which aren't totatives of $p_{i}\#$, hence $\pi(x) = \Lambda(x,p_{i}\#) + i -1 $. And, if we consider $q$, which is the largest prime divisor of $p_{i}\#$ in this case, but not $x$, then $E(x,y) = -q$ isn't bad as $q$ is small compared to $x$, but the derivation is iffy.

Comment: Your error bounds: $E(x,y) \leq 2^{\omega(y)}$ and $E(x,y) \leq \tau(y)$ are both really useful and insightful to me cheers.